# Fill area between connected segmentes (Mesh) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fill, region

I have a binary image that represents a number in MATLAB:

[image]

I'd like to fill between all black digits. The desired result is:

[image]

The only thing I found was the imfill function,

```
obj.X=imbinarize(obj.X);
obj.BW2 = imfill(obj.X,'holes');
figure;
imshow(obj.BW2);
title('Filled Image');
```

but that wasn't really helpfull, and it return White Image

Answer (score 0):

The solution in to inverse the binary image :

```
        obj.X   = imcomplement(imbinarize(obj.X));
        obj.BW2 = imcomplement(imfill(obj.X,'holes'));       
        figure;
        imshow(obj.BW2);
        title('Filled Image');
```